# Is there an easy workaround for org.hibernate.mappingexception: unknown collection role exception on Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using Hibernate 5.1.0.Final.

```
@Entity(name = "EntityA")
@Table (name = "entity_a")
public class EntityA {
    @Column
    private int a;

    @Cloumn
    private String b;

    //getters and setters
}

@Entity(name = "EntityB")
@Table (name = "entity_c")
public class EntityB {
    @Column
    private int d;

    @ManyToMany
    @NotNull
    private List<EntityA> entityAs;

    //getters and setters
}


@Entity(name = "EntityC")
@Table (name = "entity_c")
public class EntityC extends EntityB {
    @Column
    private int e;

    //getters and setters
}
```

These are basic implementations of my entities.

When I try to reach entityAs field of C with

```
queryPath.get("entityAs")
```

hibernate throws

```
org.hibernate.mappingexception: unknown collection role: my.package.entityC.entityAs
```

exception. As I understand this is a hibernate bug according to [this](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6562) issue.

I wonder is there an easy to implement workaround for this bug?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't describe your code. Post it. And when asking about an exception, always post the complete stack trace.

Comment: @JBNizet this is a problem in a project and there are lots of code. This is why I did not share the code. I will try to share a basic code to describe problem in a half hour.

Comment: @JBNizet I have added a basic code

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I was casting queryRoot to queryPath and then calling `queryPath.get("entityAs")`.

Instead of this,casting queryRoot to From and calling `queryFrom.join("entityAs", JoinType.LEFT);` has solved my problem.

Comment: This might be what you needed but it's missing all the context to be used by someone else.